# Symfony set services.yml argument from controller

Tags: symfony

Is there a way that I could set token argument from the controller?

```
app.oauth_subscriber:
    class: GuzzleHttp\Subscriber\Oauth\Oauth1
    arguments:
        - consumer_key: 'test'
          private_key_file: '../app/config/test.pem'
          private_key_passphrase: null
          signature_method: !php/const:GuzzleHttp\Subscriber\Oauth\Oauth1::SIGNATURE_METHOD_RSA
          token: "@=service('security.token_storage').getToken().getUser().getToken().getAccessToken()"
```

I can get the service like this:

```
$this->container->get('app.oauth_subscriber');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can do it with service factory or not but if you don't need token as __construct you can remove it from service arguments and declare new method in service like `setToken()` and in controller use it for set token.

```
// Service
private $token;

public function setToken($token){
    $this->token = $token;
}
```

and use `$this->token` in your service for use it.

```
 // Controller
$myService = $this->container->get('app.oauth_subscriber');
$myService->setToken('token');
```

It's just an answer. any better solution can be existing.